# One action in Rails controller sends no data back

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have these two actions in my `RelationshipController`:

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!
    respond_to :json

    def create
        user = User.find(params[:user_to_follow_id])
        relationship = current_user.follow!(user)
        respond_with user
    end

    def destroy
        user = User.find(params[:id])
        current_user.unfollow!(user)
        logger.debug user.id
        respond_with user
    end
end
```

Now when I use the create action, I get a response back with the `respond_with user` method which is also nicely formatted with `ActiveModel::Serializer`.

When I use the destroy method, I get a response back which is completely blank. It does seems to work with `render json: {user: user, status: 201}` but I am wondering why am I not able to use `respond_with` for both of them? The user they send back has the same type of data in both cases.

Unfollow method:

```
def unfollow!(user)
        $redis.multi do
            $redis.srem(self.redis_key(:following), user.id)
            $redis.srem(user.redis_key(:followers), self.id)
        end
end
```

Comment: Hmm... what does unfollow do to the passed user? If that var gets nulled out, then there's nothing to return. - ack, shoulda read closer - user seems fine if hand-constructed json response works.

Comment: It should not be the fault of that anyways. Before I respond in my destroy action, i print out to log and that shows that the user is not nulled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're bumping into the default response for action_controller / responder.rb

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb, line 203
def api_behavior(error)
  raise error unless resourceful?
  raise MissingRenderer.new(format) unless has_renderer?

  if get?
    display resource
  elsif post?
    display resource, :status => :created, :location => api_location
  else
    head :no_content
  end
end
```

If you're responding to a get or post, then some content is expected back, otherwise just a head and no content.  By default, you just deleted a relationship, so there's nothing to return. If you want to send back a user in response to a relationship deletion, then I think you'll have to craft your own response (your render son statement).